# PySerial to Connect a Pump

Tags: serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to send commands a pump listed here (page 12): https://drifton.dk/upload_dir/shop/OEM-pumps/Manualer/T100-S300-series-operating-manual-2019-7.pdf

The hardware is connected properly, and the device appears in my device manager. In my device manager I have set the parody to even, bits per second 9600, data bits to 8, and stop bit to one as specified. My simple program using serial library in python:

```
import serial

command = b"\xE9\x01\x06\x57\x4A\x01\xF4\x01\x01\xEF" #a command that should work from the manual

ser = serial.Serial("COM4", baudrate = 9600, timeout = 1)
ser.write(command)
ser.close()
```

My hardware element does not respond. Am I missing something in this program?

Comment: "*The hardware is connected properly*" -- Unless you have verified this with (successful) testing, that is really just an assumption.  You're probably working with too many unknowns at one time.  Reduce the number of untested components in your setup.  Instead of writing a your own program, first test with a terminal emulator, e.g. **minicom**, which will let you 'send' a file (precomposed with a binary/hex editor), and has a "hex" display mode to view any response.

Comment: I was able to start and control the motor using a Labview file I made ... so the motor is working and was able to receive the signal.